# Why do i need to call StateHasChanged if the method contains an await call

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Look at this code (blazor server page):

```
@page "/"

<div>@str</div>

<button @onclick="eventArgs => { OnClick(); }">Hello</button>

@code
{
   private string str { get; set; }
   private void OnClick()
   {
      str = "Hello world";
   }
}
```

This code works perfectly. I can see "Hello world" on my page when i click on the button.

Now look at this code:

```
@page "/"

<div>@str</div>

<button @onclick="eventArgs => { OnClick(); }">Hello</button>

@code
{
   private string str { get; set; }
   private async Task OnClick()
   {
      await ReadDataBase();
      str = "Hello world";
      StateHasChanged();
   }
}
```

I do not understand why but the str is not refreshed immediately if i do not put StateHasChanged(). My question is ... why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not understand why but the str is not refreshed immediately if i do not put StateHasChanged(). My question is ... why ?

This is partially true. The str variable is assigned with the string "Hello world", and the page is re-rendered only after the call to `ReadDataBase` has returned. Note that the call to `OnClick` should be awaited, like this:

```
`@onclick="async eventArgs => { await OnClick(); }"`
```

But this is not why "the str is not refreshed immediately." The reason for that is the call to the `ReadDataBase` method before you assing a value to `str`... when you await the `ReadDataBase` method  , execution is yielded to the calling code, and the framework performs other tasks... Only after the `ReadDataBase` method has returned (when the task completes), the code in the `OnClick` method continues execution of the next line which is the assignment of the string "Hello world" to `str`, and only then the component is re-rendered, if you add a call to `StateHasChanged` method or still better do `@onclick="async eventArgs => { await OnClick(); }"` and remove the call to `StateHasChanged`

Conclusion: If you want to assign a value to `str` and refresh the display immediately, place `str = "Hello world";` in the first line, and `await ReadDataBase();` in the second line. It will work without calling `StateHasChanged`, and even if you use

```
<button @onclick="eventArgs => { OnClick(); }">Hello</button>
```

instead of

```
@onclick="async eventArgs => { await OnClick(); }"
```

Incidentally, I'd do something like this:

```
<button @onclick="eventArgs => OnClick()">Hello</button>
```

Now try to understand what's the difference between `"eventArgs => OnClick()"` and  `"eventArgs => { OnClick(); }"`

Try this code:

```
<div>@str</div>

<button @onclick="OnClick">Click me</button>

@code
{
    private string str { get; set; }
    
    private async Task OnClick()
    {
        str = "Hello world";
        // Simulate an async call to ReadDataBase
        await Task.Delay(3000);

    }
}
```

Update and clarification:

I guess you know when not to call the StateHasChanged method manually, hence your question...Indeed, in the old days, one had to call this method manually, after the component's state has changed, in order to inform the component that its state had changed, and that it should re-render. Later on, the call to the StateHasChanged method manually was rendered superflous, when UI events, such as 'click' are involved. The reasoning behind it was that UI events are almost always result in the modification of the component's state, so let us save the developer the burden of adding it manually. Now, as your `OnClick` method is an event handler, adding the StateHasChanged method manually is not necessary, and yet without adding it manually the component is not refreshed (re-render). The reason for that behavior is that you call `OnClick` syncronously, without returning a Task object that should tell Blazor that the `OnClick` method has completed. In such a case, Blazor has no way to know when the `OnClick` method has completed, and thus, it does not automatically call the StateHasChanged method. But when you add the StateHasChanged method manually, the component is refreshed (re-rendered). Of course, you may not add it manually, but call the `OnClick` method asyncronously.

Comment: A race condition ? This is a baseless claim. Could you please explain and provide some code to reproduce the issue... And incidentally, I do not suggest to call `OnClick` syncronously. I just expalin that even if you call it syncronously, `str is not refreshed immediately` because `ReadDataBase` is being awaited. This is the heart of my answer. Read it once more.

Comment: Sorry i do not understand something: What do you mean by "Blue moon" ?

Comment: I would always recommend doing `<button @onclick="(eventArgs) => OnClick(eventArgs, arg1, arg2)">Hello</button>` or as covered in other answers `<button @onclick="OnClick">Hello</button>` if you have no arguments and aren't interested in the EventArgs.  Otherwise your just wrapping a Task inside a Task.....

Answer (score 3):

The reason is you are not `await`ing your async method inside your lambda. In other words, change your code to this:

```
<button @onclick="async eventArgs => { await OnClick(); }">Hello</button>
```

Having said that, if all you are doing is calling an async method and never actually use the awaited task, you can remove the brackets `{ }` and change your code to the following:

```
<button @onclick="() => OnClick()">Hello</button>
```

If you do that, the framework will wrap you lambda in a `Func<Task>` for you.

Now, I am assuming you used a lambda for a reason, such as you want to pass some arguments to it. If this is not the case you simply could make your code like the following also:

```
<button @onclick="OnClick">Hello</button>
```

When you do not await on an async method, execution continues without waiting for your task to complete. Basically, here is what happens in your code:

1. Click the button
2. ReadDataBase called
3. StateHasChanged called by framework
4. `str` not updated yet, so UI does not refresh
5. `str` finally gets updated
6. You need to call `StateHasChanged` manually to update the UI

Comment: Couldn't the code also just be `@onclick="OnClick"`?

Comment: @KirkWoll: I assumed it was just an example, but I clarified that a lambda is not necessary here in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JesseGood  You don't actually need to put the async stuff in the `@onclick`.  You can simplify it to `<button @onclick="() => OnClick()">Hello</button>`.  Subtle different, but a very different outcome.  It's all in the way the Razor compiler creates the underlying class code.  You'll also notice that the warnings disappear in Visual Studio.  You can use this to pass arguments - @onclick="(e) => OnClick(e, arg1, arg2)".

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis: I see your point, I guess the only time you need to await is if you need to do something with the result of the task, like `(e) => { var result = await DoSomething(e); result.DoNextThing(); }`.

Answer (score 1):

What your version is missing is a `return`, this will work:

```
<button @onclick="eventArgs => { return OnClick(); }">Hello</button>
```

which you can shorten to:

```
<button @onclick="eventArgs => OnClick()">Hello</button>
```

and when there are no parameters you can simplify that to just

```
<button @onclick="OnClick">Hello</button>
```

In all three cases the method assigned to `@onclick` now returns a Task and will be awaited. And then you don't need the `StatehasChanged();` line anymore.

The generated code for `@onclick=` is adapted to accepting a `Task` or `void` method and using eventArgs (or not) automatically.

Comment: Great answer.  It's that last point you made about "adapted to a Task method automatically" that I suspect is surprising for new users.  Since unusually in C#, the value for the `onclick` property is surprisingly flexible and will adapt to receivers that a) does or doesn't return a task and b) does or doesn't accept an event args parameter)

Comment: @enet not following your point?  The point of Henk's answer is that if you opt into the proper semantics for async methods you don't need to call `StateHasChanged` because it will be called automatically after the async handler completes.  OP's problem was that they **weren't** properly opting into async semantics.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: `OP's problem was that they weren't properly opting into async semantics. ` Not true... Just try the code and realize that. Also his question is very clear. Please, read my comments above, once more, then read my answer.

Comment: enet, your answer is also about async semantics.

Comment: But it is not the issue here. Read my answer once more...